# Use Fourier Transform to solve the following PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

Problem:

$u_{tt} = u_{xxxx}, t>0$

$u(0,x) = p(x)$

$u_t(0,x) = 0$

Attempt:

$F(u_{tt}) = F(u_{xxxx})$

$F(u_{tt}) = F(u)_{tt}$

$F(u_{xxxx}) = -k^4F(u)$ so $F(u)_{tt} + k^4F(u) = 0$

$e^{k^4t}F(u)_{tt} + k^4e^{k^4t}F(u) = 0$

$(e^{k^4t}F(u)_{tt} = 0$ so $e^{k^4t}F(u) = a(k)t + b(k)$

Hence $F(u) = (a(k)t + b(k))e^{-k4t}$

$u(0,x) = p(x)$

$F(u(t,k)) = (c(k)t + d(k))e^{-k^4t}$ so $F(u(0,k)) = a(k)t + b(k)$

$F(u(0,k)) = F(p(x))$ and $a(k)t + b(k) = F(p(x))$

$F(u(t,k)) = F(p(x))e^{-k^4t} := F(p(x))F(q(t,k))$

$g(t,x) = ∫_Re^{-k^4t-ikx}dk = ie^{-tk^4-ikx}/k$

$F(u) = F(pq)$ so $u(t,x) = p(x)ie^{-tk^4-ikx}/k$

I don't think the answer is correct. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

HINT :

$$F(u)_{tt}+k^4F(u)=0 \quad\to\quad F(u)=a(k)e^{ik^2t}+b(k)e^{-ik^2t}$$